# Why is cheerio not working like jquery (different results)

Tags: jquery, node.js, cheerio

**short version** Jquery: `$('img')[0]` is not equal to Cheerio: `$('img')[0]` Why?

My goal is to get the first image url for a query

I read that cheerio is a good way to parse html data much the way you do with jquery. Maybe Im wrong and there is something else better?

I load jquery into my console and visit https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=duck to set up my cheerio command.

```
    $('div img')[2].parentNode.href
```

returns

> I cant post more than two links, but it returns the correct link

Good, so now I load up node terminal and enter the following command.

```
request('https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=duck', function(e,r,d){
  console.log(cheerio.load(d)('div img')[2].parentNode.href)
})
```

returns

> undefined

and for some reason

```
request('https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=duck', function(e,r,d){
  console.log(cheerio.load(d)('div img')[2].parentNode.attribs.href)
})
```

returns

> /url?q=http://kids.nationalgeographic.com/animals/mallard-duck/&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwiPg6mE0uLUAhVD7CYKHeE9AjsQwW4IGjAC&usg=AFQjCNFBS5_1fn3v4e10lDuHmDYBvP4DSg

which is close, but a different url from what i first got on chrome console? whats going on? how do I get the same string I got on chrome console from node?

Comment: the first link i got (the one i want) in chrome console was `https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fcommons%2Fthumb%2Fa%2Fa1%2FMallard2.jpg%2F1200px-Mallard2.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FDuck_test&docid=CQ23FBiNB5egAM&tbnid=1yCi1lR9_ZrdEM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwjYx73treLUAhWGQCYKHW_tDVQQMwiLASgAMAA..i&w=1200&h=912&bih=792&biw=1380&q=duck&ved=0ahUKEwjYx73treLUAhWGQCYKHW_tDVQQMwiLASgAMAA&iact=mrc&uact=8`

Comment: The undefined is the return value of the promise.

Answer (score 2):

**Answer to your short version**: The html accessed by request() is different than the html accessed by jQuery in console.

request gets static html, whereas in the browser JavaScript can modify html once script tags or .js files are loaded. Any such changes will not be present in the html accessed by request. Using your code as an example, try running something like

```
request('https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=duck', function(e,r,d){
    console.log(d);
});
```

and save the output as an html file. Compare this html to the browser html. They are different. Note in particular, that the attributes of the image and anchor tags are different between the two.

Applying this logic to your example, my best guess is that Google -- for a reason not currently apparent to me -- runs JavaScript that changes the value of href in the anchor tags.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be patient with cheerio, it's not a big project like jQuery is.

If you're looking for a better repl I'm using async-repl and it lets me do:

```
const request = require('request-promise')
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
let $ = cheerio.load(await request('https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=duck'))
$('div img')[2].parentNode.attribs.href
// '/url?q=https://www.exoticmeatmarkets.com/product-p/pekinduckbreastboneless16.htm&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjUyfOD0afdAhXUdd4KHSzPCscQwW4IGjAC&usg=AOvVaw3IeXbIkQUTpi7FsjMVCaZy'
```

Without await everything has to happen in a callback which is annoying.

Also regarding the different link you probably get something different depending on your cookies / past searches. So try comparing to an incognito window.